# Dúvidas sobre NDK

Tags: java, android, ios, windows-phone

Estou estudando programação Android em Java, e o que me preocupa é que somente conseguirei pegar uma parcela do mercado de trabalho, porque existem celulares IOS e Windows Phone e que não utiliza a Linguagem Java, fiquei sabendo de uma ferramenta do Java chamado NDK (Native Development Kit) ela é um conjunto de ferramentas que permite desenvolver códigos nativos em C ou C++

eu gostaria de saber se através do NDK é possível fazer aplicativos para o Windows Phone?

Comment: Se sua preocupação é desenvolver um aplicativo multiplataforma, acho que você terá que ir para a área de aplicativos híbridos (html5 + camada nativa) usando PhoneGap, Appcelerator ou outros por exemplo. Usar NDK só vai ajudar a fazer código que não dependa das API's da plataforma alvo, caso contrário se possível, você vai precisar lidar com as API's (UI, GPS, Storage, etc...) de cada plataforma, que são diferentes, em seu código C++ (usar Design Patterns ajudam a reduzir o acoplamento e a criar uma abstração entre o seu código e a API's alvo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O NDK permite a portabilidade **no sentido contrário**: compilar um código C no Android. Se você tem um grande corpo de código em C, vai conseguir fazer uso dele no Android através do NDK.

Como a linguagem C é suportada na maioria das plataformas móveis, ela é uma alternativa (de que não gosto muito, mas é) para escrever código multi-plataforma.

No iOS, você pode compilar código C junto com o resto, porque Objective-C é um superconjunto de C.

No Windows Phone, que é .NET, também é possível compilar código C mas ele tem de residir numa DLL própria pois é código não gerenciado.

Deve ficar claro que o NDK não é uma ferramenta que vai fazer seu código C funcionar em todas essas plataformas. O NDK permite fazer uso código C num projeto Android, apenas.

Answer (score 1):

> eu gostaria de saber se através do NDK é possível fazer aplicativos para o Windows Phone?

Não. NDK é uma ferramenta para desenvolver em C/C++, mas ainda no Android. O que é possível é abstrair boa parte do código para uma lib em C ou C++ que poderia também ser utilizada em outras plataformas e só ligar a UI. Já vi apps com boa parte da lógica em C e uma fina casca de Java para interface no Android e Objective-C no iOS. Poderia adicionar também o suporte a Windows Phone nesse caso, mas ainda precisaria dessas camadas específicas para cada plataforma.